# Getting someone's name using regex lookahead

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm trying to use preg_match to get someone's name, but I don't want it to get their name if they say something like "my name's NOT so and so...", but I'm having trouble matching it:

```
$string = "my name is james";
preg_match("~my name is (?>!\bnot\b)[a-z]+~", $string, $match);
print_r($match);
```

Since my original string does not have the word "not" in it, it should've matched the string, but it did not. What am I doing wrong?

**Result:**

Array ( )

**Expected Result:**

Array ( my name is james )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) doesn't use `>`, [does it](https://regex101.com/r/fG5jC9/1)? (look behind does use `<`):

```
/(?!\bnot\b)[a-z]+/
```

Comment: Correct.  `(?>!\bnot\b)` is an [atomic group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/atomic.html) that matches the sequence `!not`.